# Generating multiple .txt files from a single .csv?

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv

I'm new to Python and am having a difficult time figuring out how to write a program that will write out a single .txt file for every line in a .csv file.  For instance, I have the following .csv file with data from multiple calculations and I need .txt files created for each individual calculation.  Formatting is rough to do here but the bold letters are column names and corresponding elements are underneath (ex: "Run2 and "20" belong to column C).

**A                             B        C         D**

Title:                        Run1      Run 2     Run3

"Initial Composition: FeO"       10       20        30

"Initial Composition: MgO"       40       50        60

---

I want my Python code to output the following:

**1.txt:**

Title: Run 1

Initial Composition: FeO 10

Initial Composition: Mgo: 40

---

**2.txt:**

Title: Run 2

Initial Composition: FeO 20

Initial Composition: Mgo: 50

---

The elements from A need to be printed in every .txt file with numbers from various calculations contained in columns B, C, etc... printed beside with a space.  Bonus points for anyone who can also help me create custom filenames for the .txt files based on the title (ex: the data from column A creates a .txt file called "Run1.txt."  Don't know if assigning each column to a dictionary and then appending them all together would be the best route?

Thank you!

Comment: It looks like you want us to write some code for you.

Comment: Nope, just have no idea where to even begin with this.  I've played with the csv module but didn't know if perhaps assigning each column to a dictionary and then appending them together would be the best route?  Is there even a way to custom name files?  Sorry, I'm a week into Python.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

```
with open('runs.csv','rb') as read_file:
    reader = csv.reader(read_file)
    for run in reader:
        with open(run[0] + '.txt','wb') as write_file:
            write_file.write(run[1] + '\n')
```

For a csv file with the format "Name of file","Run results", obviously this can be replaced with anything you want.

Comment: I'll try it out!  Thank you!

Comment: So lets say I have my "template" (i.e. "Title" or "Initial Composition: FeO") in column 1.  My script has to write column 1 on every output file with the contents of column 2 next to it.  The next file needs to write column 1 with contents of column 3 next to it, and so on.  Is there a specific method in Python to do this?